# How do I reload network configuration with cloud-init?

Tags: networking, 18.04, cloud, netplan, cloud-init

I've installed Ubuntu Server 18.04, and instead of the old `/etc/network/interfaces`, it seems that my network configuration now lives in a series of YAML files in `/etc/netplan`, of which the only one I actually have is `/etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by
# the datasource.  Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
# To disable cloud-init's network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        ens3:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            nameservers: {}
            optional: true
        ens4:
            addresses: []
            dhcp4: true
            dhcp6: true
            nameservers: {}
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

That seems to have been generated by `cloud-init`, from `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg`:

```
network:
  ethernets:
    ens3:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      nameservers: {}
      optional: true
    ens4:
      addresses: []
      dhcp4: true
      dhcp6: true
      nameservers: {}
      optional: true
  version: 2
```

What's the right way to edit this configuration and apply the changes to the running machine? The comment in the Netplan file suggested to me that it's ephemeral and generated on reboot by `cloud-init`, so I should edit `cloud-init`'s config. But even after editing it and rebooting, I don't see any changes to the Netplan file, and I definitely don't know how to apply the `cloud-init` config changes manually. And upon reading the comment again, now it seems to me that it's talking about changes not persisting across *destruction and recreation of the machine*, which would seem to go without saying. So clearly I'm misunderstanding something.

So my question is:

1. Where in the new `cloud-init`/`netplan` system am I *supposed* to be putting manual network configuration?
2. How do I apply changes I make in `/etc/netplan`?
3. How do I apply changes I make in `/etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you backup the current `/etc/netplan/*.yaml` file to something like `/etc/netplan/*.yaml.BAK`.

Then you make any changes you desire to `/etc/netplan/*.yaml`. Indentation and spacing and no tabs, are VERY important when creating/editing a .yaml file.

FYI: your existing .yaml files should start with:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
```

Then:

`sudo netplan --debug generate` # generate config files

`sudo netplan apply` # apply to the current system

`reboot` # to confirm proper operation

For further examples and configuration guidelines see https://netplan.io/examples

Comment: This only answers the first part of the question where netplan --debug apply is sufficient (no generate needed) but the cloud-init file /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/50-curtin-networking.cfg if you change it there it never auto generates the netplan file, and that is suppose to come from nocloud (seed.iso or nocloud-net meta-data)?

Comment: @MasterJames the reason to do a generate first, is so that you can catch and correct any errors before the actual apply. If you use only apply, and there's an error, it could take down a running server. I can't speak to the rest of your comment.

Answer (score 13):

It seems the trick to getting the yaml to generate from the cfg is...

```
cloud-init clean -r
```

Next problem is how to get that cfg set from the seed.iso or nocloud-net meta-data

the r flag is the same as any reboot `shutdown -r now`

If you run `cloud-init init` (without rebooting) there is not visible change to /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml

So still not clear on how to trigger that without the reboot?
I've tried `cloud-init init` and then `systemctl restart cloud-init`

I have also tried `cloud-init -d modules --mode config` and `cloud-init -d modules --mode final`

Okay wait I think I found it...

```
systemctl restart cloud-init-local.service
```

it seems to rebuild the netplan yaml from the cloud cfg after you `cloud-init clean` running `cloud-init init` does not do it. **[Ubuntu 19.04 cloud-init 19]**

*[too many moving parts in this design]*

Note: I have found an improvement which brings further clarity both these commands achieve the desired result.

```
cloud-init clean --logs
cloud-init init --local
```

Comment: this is just awful.

Comment: In what way BjornW? are you dissatisfied with cloud-init itself as I am, my showing the path of discovery (which demonstrates what works and doesn't), or what did you not understand. It might be awful but it is not 'just awful' because it also shows how to actually do it. Anyway if you could be constructive in your criticism, maybe I could address your concerns.

Comment: exactly, I was just annoyed at cloud init (and netplan..) no critisism of your answer itself :) I ended up with simply apt-get remove cloud-init..

Comment: Yup it seems writing your own script is still just as good in my books. Getting AWS ENIs attached etc. is complicated but seems required in regards to running IPv4 and IPv6 addresses [per-cpu] for an instances CPUs-1 anyway, so it's virtually pointless to use cloud-init in the end.

Comment: You may want to mention, up front, that `cloud-init clean -r` reboots the server and changes the server host key. Both of those things were surprises to me.

Comment: Which of the two last mentioned commands has the least impact on the system? I just want to switch from DHCP to static.

Comment: Just a word of caution: cloud-init clean will do a lot more than just reset the network configuration; it resets pretty much everything that uniquely identifies the system, such as SSH host keys, UUIDs that may be registered in management systems, etc. In a simple setup, cloud-init clean can be a valid workaround, but in ocmplex setups it is very dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Since [version **23.4** of **cloud-init**](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/main/ChangeLog#L219) a new option is added to the `clean` subcommand: [--configs](https://cloudinit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/cli.html#clean)

At the moment of writing this version of **cloud-init** is in the ['proposed' phase for Ubuntu Jammy](https://answers.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cloud-init/23.4.3-0ubuntu0%7E22.04.1/+publishinghistory) so you can **not** get it using `apt-get update`.

I checked the [source](https://github.com/canonical/cloud-init/blob/ubuntu/23.4.3-0ubuntu0_22.04.1/cloudinit/cmd/clean.py) what the command does and it removes certain files and directories. After some testing I found out this way we can manually make **cloud-init** re-generate the network configuration:

#### Minimal changes to make cloud-init regenerate the network configuration

```
sudo rm /var/lib/cloud/data/instance-id
sudo cloud-init init --local
```

This does not reboot the machine nor change the SSH host key.

To apply the new **netplan** config execute:

```
sudo netplan apply
```

---

#### Alternative method:

Install the 'proposed' package manually:

```
cd /tmp
wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/713462297/cloud-init_23.4.3-0ubuntu0~22.04.1_all.deb
sudo apt-get install ./cloud-init_23.4.*.deb
```

Check the version of **cloud-init**:

```
cloud-init --version
```

It should be `23.4.0` or higher, for example `/usr/bin/cloud-init 23.4.3-0ubuntu0~22.04.1`

Now you can execute this command to clean and regenerate only your network config:

```
sudo cloud-init clean --configs network
sudo cloud-init init --local
```

This will change the SSH host key but won't reboot the machine.