# assign static IP ubuntu 18.04

Tags: networking, server, 18.04, webserver

I'm seeing a lot of guides on internet telling me to assign through

```
cd /etc/netplan

sudo nano 50-cloud-init.yaml
```

Unfortunately I edited it with tabs at first and now I'm not sure how to fix that mistake.

Also, it says that changes in this file will not take effect!

```
#This file is generated from information provided by
#the datasource. Changes to it will not persist across an instance.
```

How can I revert this file back to default and make the proper edits to assign our Ubuntu server a static IP?

Comment: Edit the .yaml with gedit and it'll show you where the tabs are. `sudo -H gedit /etc/netplan/50-cloud-init.yaml`

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example: [How do I reload network configuration with cloud-init?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1104285/how-do-i-reload-network-configuration-with-cloud-init?rq=1). Also, you can try to revert back to the original file format which is stated below.

```
network:
    ethernets:
        eno1: <-- or whatever your connection states it is
            dhcp4: yes
version2:
```

This should do it. This is the default config. for the .yaml src at 50-cloud-init.yaml at /etc/netplan/.

Seth

P.S. Then, use `sudo netplan apply` to finish off your "change." If the sudo netplan apply command does not work, try to look around on this forum. I have found some info. that is dedicated to netplan or ubuntu server specifically.